# How do I get emoticons working in express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

`bodyParser.json` crashes when provided with an emoji. It seems like it cannot handle the utf8b4 charset. I have searched all over for a json parser that can handle emojis, but it seems like all the modules that deal with this kind of thing are browser related or do not fit the scope of what I am trying to achieve. There must be a way to get emojis working in Express, but I cannot find any information on it at all. How do I get emoticons working in express?

Comment: I posted that question and it was never resolved. Again, it appears like this is a subject where there is virtually NO support in the Node community.

Comment: You posted that question yesterday and you think of it as 'never resolved' and repost today?  You also never bothered to answer the comment asking you what version you are using.  I think you should stick with the original post from yesterday to keep confusion to a minimum.